# Javascript Reset a function after collision right

Tags: javascript, html, css, collision-detection

I'm trying to reset a bar if my player walks on a tile (water1, water2, water3 variables). When the player collides with one of these three tiles, the bar resets. If my player didn't walk on the tiles and the bar is on 100, you get a Game Over screen.

It works so far, but the problem is, when the player collides with the water tile, the bar resets to start, but the counter to the Game Over screen didn't reset.

For example: If I reset the bar when it's at 40%, it goes back to 0, but after the bar goes another 60% I get the Game Over Screen, not after 100% like I want.

```
var water1 = {x: 352, y: 64, width: 32, height: 32}
var water2 = {x: 352, y: 96, width: 32, height: 32}
var water3 = {x: 384, y: 64, width: 32, height: 32}

function thirst() {                                                                                                     
      var elem2 = document.getElementById("durst");   
      var width = 1;
      var id2 = setInterval(frame, 1000);
      function frame() {
             if (player.xPos < water1.x + water1.width &&
                    player.xPos + player.width > water1.x &&
                    player.yPos < water1.y + water1.height &&
                    player.height + player.yPos > water1.y) {
                    thirst();
                    return;
                    }   if (player.xPos < water2.x + water2.width &&
                            player.xPos + player.width > water2.x &&
                            player.yPos < water2.y + water2.height &&
                            player.height + player.yPos > water2.y) {
                            thirst();
                            return;
                        }       if (player.xPos < water3.x + water3.width &&
                                    player.xPos + player.width > water3.x &&
                                    player.yPos < water3.y + water3.height &&
                                    player.height + player.yPos > water3.y) {
                                    thirst();
                                    return;
                                }       if (width >= 100) {
                                            clearInterval(id2);
                                        }    else {
                                                width++; 
                                                elem2.style.width = width + '%'; 
                                            }       if(width == 100) {
                                                        location.href = '666_GameOver.html';
                                                    }       
        }       
}
```

CSS

```
#balkenDurst {                                                                                                                          
      width: 5%;
      background-color: #0000ff;
      z-index: 4;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 8% ;
    }

    #durst {
      width: 0%;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      z-index: 4;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="balkenDurst">
  <div id="durst"></div>
</div>
```

Maybe you have an idea what's wrong.

I know I could write it with less code, but I'm learning and I'm really glad it works so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Programming with objects

Okay, i see your close to your target with the collision detection and the methods you use.
There are some issues with the code, and thats for you to fix.
But i got some pointers for you.

#### Water tiles

In your code:

```
if (player.xPos < water1.x + water1.width &&
                player.xPos + player.width > water1.x &&
                player.yPos < water1.y + water1.height &&
                player.height + player.yPos > water1.y) {
    thirst();
    return;
}
```

This is repeated multiple times. Try to avoid repeating the same code over and over.
You can easily change it to become a function you can call multiple times.

Here is an example:

```
function hit( tile) {
    //Hits on x axis
    if(player.xPos < tile.x + tile.width && player.xPos + player.width > tile.x) {
        //Hits on y axis
        if (player.yPos < tile.y + tile.height && player.yPos + player.height > tile.y) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: Is it not easier to read the code now?
Now since we made it into a fuction it can take in any tile!

Like say water tiles.

```
//Defines our water tiles in an array. (Easier to use)
var waterTiles = [
    {x: 352, y: 64, width: 32, height: 32},
    {x: 352, y: 96, width: 32, height: 32},
    {x: 384, y: 64, width: 32, height: 32},
];

//Checks if any of the water tiles hit

function checkHits() {
    for (var i = 0; i < waterTiles.length; i++) {
        //Use our method above.
        var check = hit ( waterTiles[i] );
        if (check) {
            //Code to check if it hits.
        }
    }
}
```

This is nice and all, but you did not answer my question.
Okay so going to the thirst logic of your game.

How you are setting with with of the thirst bar is not shown in your code above.

But since your thirst bar is not reseting probably it sounds like a variable not being reset correctly.

If you have a `var thirst` defined and a `var width` of the bar. You need to change both.
So in your thirst method set the thirst level: `player.thirst = 60;` (example).
Then in your frame() method (usualy called "update" in game loops) get this thirt something like: `var width = player.thirst`
When you decrease it (each frame?) Just set the variable again: `player.thirst = player.thirst - 1;`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.  Yeah, the code looks more easy as my code :D I will try it with this code. The width of my bar is set in the css.  I got the basis for the bar from here (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp) Its pobably not the best for this, but until my reset problem it works good for me. And because its for a school project, and i havn't this much time, this bar is ok for me.